Export Open Buildings Temporal V1 at a specific resolution after masking out unwanted pixels
I want to export Open Buildings Temporal V1 building height (BH) data at a specified resolution for a specific area. The area is based on an asset I'm importing (a polygon shapfile). What I can't do is to use the building_presence band to set a threshold (for example 0.7) to mask out unwanted pixels (below that threshold). From the dataset's code editor I don't really understand how I can mask out pixels below that threshold.
Also, I have tried to resample the image to the desired resolution (130m) before exporting but the resulting raster has null values. I'd like to use use the average as a resampling method and not GEE's default nearest neighbour. Here is one example out of the many attempts to download BH for the year 2019:
In GEE, the buildings are shown just fine:

But when I try to import them into a GIS software:

Clearly, I am missing something here. How can I use the building_presence band to mask out unwanted pixels and export the resulting image at a specified resolution?
var col = ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/Research/open-buildings-temporal/v1')
            .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31');  // Filter for the year 2018

/**
 * Adds building presence and height layers for a given timestamp.
 * @param {number} millis Timestamp in milliseconds.
 */
function addLayers(millis) {
  // Create a mosaic of tiles with the same timestamp.
  var mosaic = col.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:time_start', millis)).mosaic();
  var year = new Date(millis).getFullYear();
  Map.addLayer(
      mosaic.select('building_presence'), {max: 1},
      'building_presence_conf_' + year);
  Map.addLayer(
      mosaic.select('building_height'), {max: 100}, 'building_height_m_' + year,
      /*shown=*/ false);
}

var ts = col.filterBounds(geometry)
             .aggregate_array('system:time_start')
             .distinct()
             .sort()
             .getInfo();

ts.forEach(addLayers);

var grid= geometry.geometry(130)
// Calculate the mean building height within each grid cell
var meanHeight = col.select('building_height')
                    .mean()
                    .reduceRegions({
                      collection: grid,
                      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
                      scale: 130
                    });

// Convert the result to a raster TIFF file
var raster = meanHeight.reduceToImage({
  properties: ['mean'],
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first()
});

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: raster,
  description: 'mean_building_height_2018',
  scale: 130,
  region: geometry,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
});

Map.centerObject(geometry, 10);

The shp I am using.

Your question seems to be twofold: 1-) masking out building where presence value is less than specific threshold (0.7). 2-) Averaging the building heights within a specific cell size (130). The first can be achieved using .updateMask() and the latter, although inefficient, can be done using .reduceResolution()
    var BF0 = ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/Research/open-buildings-temporal/v1')
            .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31').filterBounds(geometry)
var proj = BF0.first().projection();
var BF = BF0.mosaic()
            .clip(geometry).setDefaultProjection(proj);
            
Map.addLayer(BF,{},'Original BF')
// Mask of building presense threshold 0.7
var BF = BF.updateMask(BF.select('building_presence').gt(0.7)).unmask()
Map.addLayer(BF,{},'masked BF')

//Aggregate or reduce resolution using mean

var cellsize1 = 65 // you specified 130! The aggregation from original resolution 0.5 to 130 involve large number of pixels that exceeds maxpixel allowed  67600. We need to do it in two steps 65*2 
var meanHeight1 = BF.select('building_height')
    .reduceResolution({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      maxPixels : 16900 //(65/0.5)^2
    }).reproject(
      {crs: proj, scale: cellsize1
    }).rename('Mean');
var cellsize2 = 130 //65*2=130
var meanHeight = meanHeight1
    .reduceResolution({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      maxPixels : 4 //(130/65)^2
    }).reproject(
      {crs: proj, scale: cellsize2
    })
Map.addLayer(meanHeight,{},'Mean heights at 130 cell size')


Export.image.toDrive({
  image: meanHeight,
  description: 'mean_building_height_2018',
  scale: 130,
  region: geometry,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
});

Map.centerObject(geometry, 15);


Can I ask why using reduceResolution is inefficient? What would be an efficient way?

The reason for that is it requires to reproject (See best practices here about avoiding reproject https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#avoid_reproject). The code still work just fine, and I don't know better way! This might be an issue for large regions or where you need to do further heavy analysis before export

Tha is for the link. I'm using GEE just to download the data, so I guess it's fine to use reproject.

For larger regions it show an error about the allowed maximum pixels (2^31).

Can you share the full error message! I would expect memory limits message not maxPixels based on the reprojection limitation I mentioned

Okay, this is a new message: Mean heights at 130 cell size: Tile error: User memory limit exceeded. x4
Regarding the previous error, I am trying to reproduce it. When I do, I'll post the exact error.
